# jasonp cross domain request "wrapping json into a callback method"

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I added  ?callback=? to the url in the get request with an anonymous function, what do I have to add to my server side code to make it work cross domain.

Is it right to use getJSON here?

here is an example of the player without JSONP
http://www.freeenergymedia.com/shared/PLAYER/player/player.php

PHP script which returns JSON data

```
  <?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
$url = 'http://www.startalkradio.net/?page_id=354';
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);

$items = $rss->channel->item;


$i = 0;
$data = array();
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $data[] = array(
        'title' => (string) $item->title,
        'mp3'   => (string) $item->enclosure['url'],

    );
    if (++$i == 3) break;
}


$jsdata = json_encode($data);
$test = htmlspecialchars($jsdata, ENT_NOQUOTES, 'utf-8');

$jsdata = ($_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($data).');'); 

echo $jsdata
?>
```

get request, loads JSON into player

```
   $(document).ready(function() {


    $.getJSON("http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php?callback=?", function callback(json) 
    {

        new jPlayerPlaylist({
            jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
            cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
        }, json, {
            swfPath: "js",
            supplied: "mp3, oga",
            wmode: "window"
        });
    })
});
```

markup

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />


<title>Demo : jPlayer as an audio playlist player</title>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />



</head>
<body>



<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.freeenergymedia.com/shared/PLAYER/player/js/jquery.jplayer.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.freeenergymedia.com/shared/PLAYER/player/js/jplayer.playlist.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.freeenergymedia.com/shared/PLAYER/player/ajax.js"></script>
<link href="http://www.freeenergymedia.com/shared/PLAYER/player/skin/pink.flag/jplayer.pink.flag.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div style="margin:0 auto; padding: 10% 0 0 0; width: 250px;">
        <div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>

        <div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
            <div class="jp-type-playlist">
            <div id="logo"><img src="http://freeenergymedia.com/startalk.png"/></div>
                <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
                    <ul class="jp-controls">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-previous" tabindex="1">previous</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1">pause</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-next" tabindex="1">next</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute">unmute</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="jp-progress">
                        <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                            <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                        <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
                    <div class="jp-duration"></div>
                    <ul class="jp-toggles">
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle" tabindex="1" title="shuffle">shuffle</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-shuffle-off" tabindex="1" title="shuffle off">shuffle off</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                        <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off">repeat off</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="jp-playlist">
                    <ul>
                        <li></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>      
                <div class="jp-no-solution">
                    <span>Update Required</span>
                    To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>      
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PHP script is returning JSONP and not JSONP. To make it working cross-domain you must actually modify your PHP to return a call to a callback function.

So you must make sure that the PHP code is returning data in a form `callback(data);`.

```
$jsdata = ($_GET['callback'].'('.json_encode($data).');');
```

Change your JavaScript `.getJSON()` call to:

```
$.getJSON("http://www.freeenergymedia.com/getxml2.php?callback=?", function(json) {
  // ... rest of the code
});
```

jQuery will insert into the URL generated callback name.

See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

Comment: what is the "generated callback name" is it random?

Comment: It is random callback generated by jQuery and passed as a GET parameter. You don't need to deal with any details - just make sure it is "called" by returning the `callback(data)` where `callback` =  `$_GET['callback']` and `data` are your JSON data.

Comment: @userAgent Where did you get that `"","",JSONP`? Are they supposed to be `getJSON` parameters? Just use `getJSON(url, function(json) { });`. See [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/). No idea what is that doing there :).

Comment: um I thought I was specifying dataType parameter. Guess not.

Comment: @userAgent 1) It is outside the `$.getJSON()` call. 2) `$.getJSON()` takes 2-3 arguments :). It should detect you want JSONP by checking your `callback=?` parameter and switch into it automatically. If you want to configure anything else, then use for example `$.ajax()` instead, but you probably don't.